# Mysql How to rename a resulting row after using union and sum

Tags: mysql, select, sum, union

I don't know if it's a stupid wish. I'll try to explain.

For example the table has `category 1, category 2, category 3, category 4` and all hours are equal to `10`.
I want to get the sum of all hours from category 1, and sum of all hours of all other categories except first.

Query:

```
SELECT category, sum(hours) from data WHERE category='category 1' 
UNION
SELECT category, sum(hours) from data WHERE category<>'category 1'
```

Result:

```
category sum(hours)
category 1 | 10
category 2 | 30
```

I want it to be like that, to rename second row, because it chooses it's name by itself. From `category 2` to `all others`.

```
category sum(hours)
category 1 | 10
all others | 30
```

I googled for an hour, but i can only find how to rename Column, but not the resulting row. Any ideas?

Comment: is category a column name ? i thought that you did say category 1 is the column name

Comment: Sorry, if i did a mistake. It's hard to explain what i wanted. But i already got an answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the value of the `category` column you can set a string value:

```
SELECT category, SUM(hours) FROM data WHERE category = 'category 1' 
UNION
SELECT 'all others', SUM(hours) FROM data WHERE category <> 'category 1'
```

---

You can also use a single query using [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) to get the result:

```
SELECT 
    IF(category = 'category 1', category, 'all others') AS category, 
    SUM(hours) 
FROM data
GROUP BY IF(category = 'category 1', category, 'all others');
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87e085/9/1

Comment: Oh fudge! I knew it's something simple, but just couldn't get around it!
In all examples they show `SELECT category AS 'all others'` i didn't know you can do it reverse.
I'll mark it as answer in 10 min.

Comment: The alias in the second half of the query is not needed and will be ignored.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - You are right. Only needed on the first statement.